# How do I classify files in Linux server by their names?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

How can use the ls command and options to list the repetitious filenames that are in different directories?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Cyrus, it's a fair comment.  It turns out to be more complicated than a simple bash globbing question and requires some arguable degree of programming (however slight), although the questioner was not aware of it at the time he asked it.  So I've answered it here. But you're correct, as asked it's more Super User oriented.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" if it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a single, basic `ls` command to do this.  You'd have to use a combination of other POSIX/Unix/GNU utilities.  For example, to find the duplicate filenames first:

```
find . -type f -exec basename "\{}" \; | sort | uniq -d > dupes
```

This means `find` all the files (`-type f`) through the entire directory hierarchy in the current directory (`.`), and execute (`-exec`) the command `basename` (which strips the directory portion) on the found file (`\{}`), end of command (`\;`).  These files then sort and print out duplicate lines (`uniq -d`).  The result goes in the file `dupes`.  Now you have the filenames that are duplicated, but you don't know what directory they are in.  Use `find` again to find them.  Using `bash` as your shell:

```
while read filename; do find . -name "$filename" -print; done < dupes
```

This means loop through (`while`) all contents of file `dupes` and `read` into the variable `filename` each line.  For each line, execute `find` again and search for the specific `-name` of the `$filename` and print it out (`-print`, but it's implicit so this is redundant).

Truth be told you can combine these without using an intermediate file:

```
find . -type f -exec basename "\{}" \; | sort | uniq -d | while read filename; do find . -name "$filename" -print; done
```

If you're not familiar with it, the `|` operator means, execute the following command using the output of the previous command as the input to the following command. Example:

```
eje@EEWANCO-PC:~$ mkdir test
eje@EEWANCO-PC:~$ cd test
eje@EEWANCO-PC:~/test$ mkdir 1 2 3 4 5
eje@EEWANCO-PC:~/test$ mkdir 1/2 2/3
eje@EEWANCO-PC:~/test$ touch 1/0000 2/1111 3/2222 4/2222 5/0000 1/2/1111 2/3/4444
eje@EEWANCO-PC:~/test$ find . -type f -exec basename "\{}" \; | sort | uniq -d | while read filename; do find . -name "$filename" -print; done
./1/0000
./5/0000
./1/2/1111
./2/1111
./3/2222
./4/2222
```

Disclaimer:  The requirement stated that the filenames were all numbers. While I have tried to design the code to handle filenames with spaces (and in tests on my system, it works), the code may break when it encounters special characters, newlines, nuls, or other unusual situations.  Please note that the `-exec` parameter has special security considerations and should not be used by root over arbitrary user files. The simplified example provided is intended for illustrative and didactic purposes only.  Please consult your `man` pages and relevant CERT advisories for full security implications.

Comment: Touch a file with name "file01 01 17" in a couple of locations and try your code.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, works for me, I tried it.  Besides, the poster indicated that his filenames were all numbers.  There was no requirement to handle filenames with spaces, so I did not specifically test the code for that scenario.  I'll add a disclaimer, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function in my bash profile (bash 4.4) for duplicate files. 
It is true that find is the correct tool.

I use find combined with `-print0` options which separates the find results with null char instead of new lines (default find action). Now i can catch all files under current directory and subdirectories.

This will ensure that results will be correct no matter if filenames contain special chars like spaces or new lines (in some very rare cases). Instead of double running find against find, you can built an array and just locate the duplicate files in this array. Then you grep the whole array using the "duplicates" as pattern.

So something like this works ok for my function:

```
$ IFS= readarray -t -d '' fn< <(find . -name 'file*' -print0)
$ dupes=$(LC_ALL=C sort <(printf '\<%s\>$\n' "${fn[@]##*/}") |uniq -d)
$ grep -e "$dupes" <(printf '%s\n' "${fn[@]}")  |awk -F/ '{print $NF,"==>",$0}' |LC_ALL=C sort
```

This is a test:

```
$ IFS= readarray -t -d '' fn< <(find . -name 'file*' -print0)
# find all files and load them in an array using null delimiter
$ printf '%s\n' "${fn[@]}" #print the array
./tmp/file7
./tmp/file14
./tmp/file11
./tmp/file8
./tmp/file9
./tmp/tmp2/file09 99
./tmp/tmp2/file14.txt
./tmp/tmp2/file15.txt
./tmp/tmp2/file$100
./tmp/tmp2/file14.txt.bak
./tmp/tmp2/file15.txt.bak
./tmp/file1
./tmp/file4
./file09 99
./file14
./file$100
./file1

$ dupes=$(LC_ALL=C sort <(printf '\<%s\>$\n' "${fn[@]##*/}") |uniq -d)
#Locate duplicate files
$ echo "$dupes"
\<file$100\>$ #Mind this one with special char $ in filename
\<file09 99\>$ #Mind also this one with spaces
\<file14\>$
\<file1\>$
#I have on purpose enclose the results between \<...\> to force grep later to capture full words and avoid file1 to match file1.txt or file11

$ grep -e "$dupes" <(printf '%s\n' "${fn[@]}")  |awk -F/ '{print $NF,"==>",$0}' |LC_ALL=C sort
file$100 ==> ./file$100          #File with special char correctly captured
file$100 ==> ./tmp/tmp2/file$100
file09 99 ==> ./file09 99        #File with spaces in name also correctly captured
file09 99 ==> ./tmp/tmp2/file09 99
file1 ==> ./file1
file1 ==> ./tmp/file1
file14 ==> ./file14              #other files named file14 like file14.txt and file14.txt.bak not captured since they are not duplicates.
file14 ==> ./tmp/file14
```

Tips:

- This one `<(printf '\<%s\>$\n' "${fn[@]##*/}")` uses process substitution on the basename of the find results using bash built in parameter expansion techniques.
- LC_ALL=C is required on sorting in order filenames to be sorted correctly.
- In bash versions before 4.4 , the readarray does not accept -d option (delimiter). In this case you can transform find results to an array with

  while IFS= read -r -d '' res;do fn+=( "$res" );done < <(find.... -print0)